# joomla administrator. Can't access my artilces and menus

Tags: php

Evey time I try to access my articles It displys this error message below. what can I do. Pls advice.
500 - An error has occurred!
DB function failed with error number 145
Table '.\wai3\jos_content' is marked as crashed and should be repaired SQL=SELECT c.*, g.name AS groupname, cc.title AS name, u.name AS editor, f.content_id AS frontpage, s.title AS section_name, v.name AS author FROM jos_content AS c LEFT JOIN jos_categories AS cc ON cc.id = c.catid LEFT JOIN jos_sections AS s ON s.id = c.sectionid LEFT JOIN jos_groups AS g ON g.id = c.access LEFT JOIN jos_users AS u ON u.id = c.checked_out LEFT JOIN jos_users AS v ON v.id = c.created_by LEFT JOIN jos_content_frontpage AS f ON f.content_id = c.id WHERE c.state != -2 ORDER BY section_name , section_name, cc.title, c.ordering LIMIT 0, 20

Answer (score 2):

> `' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

is the key.

Try sending a [REPAIR TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html) command in the database tool of your choice.

If that doesn't help, you probably need to talk to your server administrator and ask them to fix the problem.